# Scroll to div after php code

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I would like to scroll to a div after running a php code that runs when i press the  it searches the database and posts to a table thats located in that div

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $searchvalue = $_POST['searchvalue'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(`user_id`, `user_username`, `user_password`, `user_name`, `user_gender`, `user_age`, `user_contact`, `user_email`, `user_address`, `user_industry`, `user_findout`, `user_admin`) LIKE '%".$searchvalue."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    echo"
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.graph').offset().top
            },
                'slow');
        })
    </script>";
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to get that to work that has you stumped? And is the PHP you posted called from ajax of some sort? You did not include any js code samples.

Comment: I've tried echo"function () {
       $('html,body').animate({
           scrollTop: $('.graph').offset().top
       },
     'slow');
   })"; after the php code

Comment: Can you provide us with your html and jquery?

Comment: Try to enclose the `animate` function in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` block as `.graph` probably doesn't exist until the page is loaded

Comment: It doesnt work as it seems to run the javascript before reloading the page @Steve T

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: You're including users passwords in to the search??

Comment: ignore the query it was something i took straight out of phpadmin ill be changing it later on xD

Comment: Do you include jquery? Do you have a div or table with a graph css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session_start()` needs to be before any `HTML` output so that means somewhere above the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. The rest of the code should be in the `body` of the document so you can run the `script`.

Also, use the `$( window ).load();` instead of `$(document).ready();` to be sure that the whole HTML page is loaded including `CSS` and `javascript` files.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  // at least use some kind of escaping.. (Use prepared statements!)
  $searchvalue = mysqli_real_eascape_string($conn, $_POST['searchvalue']);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE CONCAT(`user_id`, `user_username`, `user_password`, `user_name`, `user_gender`, `user_age`, `user_contact`, `user_email`, `user_address`, `user_industry`, `user_findout`, `user_admin`) LIKE '%".$searchvalue."%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     $( window ).load(function()
     {
          $("html,body").animate({
              scrollTop: $(".graph").offset().top
          },
             "slow");
     });
  </script>';
else
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** To help make your application more secure, I would suggest looking into **`mysqli prepared statements`**. Read on prepared statements: [http://php.net/prepared-statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: You're missing a reference to jQuery in your code and the `<div class="graph"></div>`.

Comment: Much thanks it works !

Comment: @SteveT you are right, I am missing a reference. Maybe the OP's scripts are loaded at the bottom of the `body`, maybe in the `head` or somewhere else, it is irrelevant. That is why i used `window.load` method, to be sure the `jquery` has been loaded wherever the OP put it. And that is why I didn't add the `jquery`, to keep it simple. The same goes for the `div` (the OP didn't show the div either).

Comment: @yl2201 your welcome :) And please consider using **`prepared statements`** in `mysqli`, the  main difference between `mysql` and `mysqli` was the introduction of `prepared statements`, and... the `i` in `mysqli` stands for `improved`. Otherwise you are prone to SQL injection attacks. Peace